# Best fit assemble a geometric model to another model according to the geometric variation

Tags: optimization

If I have a geometric model that has geometric variation from the nominal dimensions and I want to assemble it to a second geometric model with variation, how do I best fit them together to minimise the variation?

Comment: What is geometric variation?

Comment: variance of the geometric distribution??? cant be right .. lol

Comment: @zoli During the manufacture of components a variations to the nominal dimensions is generated. It is deviation from nominal that I want to account for.